# having an issue with select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that im certain is correct but alas it is not.  and that being said i am at a loss as to what could be causing the issue.  here is my php script.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE);
if(!$con){
echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
 echo "Database connection Success...";
}

$user_name = $_POST["login_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["login_pass"];

$sql_query = "SELECT name from user_info where user_name like '$user_name'
and user_pass like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row ["name"];
echo "Hello welcome".$name;

}

 else {
 echo "No user found";

 }




 ?>
```

Comment: Not only are you missing quotes, your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries). You also should never store passwords as plain text. Use [password hash to protect them](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/530/password-hashing-functions)

Comment: what error(s) are you getting (check your error log) and what do you mean when you say it isn't working? Is the query running? Are you getting any output? This question lacks even basic debugging attempts like doing  a `var_dump` on variables to double check their values. var_dump the query, check that it looks correct. var_dump the result and check that it didn't return false/null. var_dump num_rows to see how many rows are returned. run the query in another program to see if any rows come back. double check that the table has a row that should match what you expect...etc

Comment: It won't select the name from the database

Comment: And there aren't any errors just my else statement saying no user found

Answer (score 2):

You haven't hadded quotes! Remember `$query` is a string!

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_DATABASE);

if(!$con) {
echo "Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
 echo "Database connection Success...";
}

$user_name = $_POST["login_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["login_pass"];

$sql_query = "SELECT name from user_info WHERE user_name like '$user_name'
and user_pass like '$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $name = $row ["name"];
  echo "Hello welcome".$name; 
} else {
  echo "No user found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your query string in quotes.
You are writing query in your PHP variable so it must be wrapped in quotes.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT name from user_info where user_name like '{$user_name}' and user_pass like '{$user_pass'}";
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you experiencing?

Your query should be a string, which means you'll need to surround it with quotes when assigning it:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT name from user_info where user_name like '" . $user_name
. "' and user_pass like '" . $user_pass . "'";
```

you can also use this syntax:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT name from user_info where user_name like '{$user_name}' and user_pass like '{$user_pass}'";
```

This will, however leave you open to SQL Injection Attacks.
See [this part of the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more.

Comment: My query was a string I was trying everything and forgot to put it back for the question so even as a string it's still not working